# Raspberry Pi Pico not mounting

Tags: ubuntu, pi-pico

My raspberry pi pico has been (auto) mounting fine so far but suddenly it has stopped doing so.

More specifically, when I was plugging it into the usb port (pushing down BOOTSEL) of an Ubuntu machine (22.04.1 LTS) it was getting picked-up and auto-mounted but that's not the case anymore.

Running `ls -ll /media/<user>/` isn't listing that either so it can't be mounted manually.

The user has also been added to the `dialout` group.

Any ideas? Is that an Ubuntu issue?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your Ubuntu is broken. Perhaps try Win or Mac.

Comment: your description is vague ... what was automounting where?

Comment: apologies, what I meant was that previously when pico was inserted into the usb port, Ubuntu would pick that up as an external storage device, mount it  (I _think_) under /media/<user>/Some_Dir and then open-up a window to let you access the mounted directory. This suddenly stopped happening for some reason. I tried tailing the kernel logs to see what happens when pico is unplugged and then plugged again (basically, in an attempt to find out where in /dev my usb port is so that I can mount that manually) but no messages are printed. Pretty sure the connections are ok.

Comment: probably an ubuntu issue to be fair..

Comment: You should use the command `lsblk` that will show all storage devices, even if NOT mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. It turns out that not all USB cables are created equal. If I use an inexpensive charging cable on the pico, it doesn't mount. I use a "better" cable (it does appear to be a little thicker wire), it mounts without issue. If you're using the same cable and it's stopped mounting, I expect that this is not the issue. Hope you find it!
k

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/125040)